# Visual Leak Detector VLD truncates pointer 64 bit

Tags: c, 64-bit

VLD is only reporting the last 8 digits of the leaked memory address.
For example here is a leak from the VLD report:

```
---------- Block 14207110 at 0x00000000185AB1E0: 528 bytes ----------
  Leak Hash: 0xE6C357C7, Count: 16118, Total 8510304 bytes
  Call Stack:
    ucrtbased.dll!malloc()
```

But the address of this memory (from the debugger) is: **00000154185AB1E0**

I assume precision is lost somewhere along the way in VLD because it stores the pointer in a 32 bit int?

Is there a way to get VLD to report the entire 64bit pointer?

Thanks!

I tried reading the VLD help.